# is There any way to control programs by finding from task manager and managing contents?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, controls

Hello guess my title is bad enough to explain question but I am trying to understand is there any way to control and automate things just finding tasks from task manager? I have seen in Visual Studio "Spy++". Firstly, i didn't understand what it's aim and how far we can go with it. I just got it, it can provide us logs in a cool range.

**I would like to give an example,**

*I want to log in Facebook/Twitter and do casual things with developed software by myself(I don't want to use selenium or any kind of that thing) or I want to get informations from a game which is about characters actual health, attack power, ability power... or giving command that game from my software like, press a,b or 1.
Can someone tell me, exact subject name of what i am talking about?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology: Selenium / AutoIt: "UI automation". Reading and modifying in-game values: "memory editor" or "trainer".

There is no universal way to control programs if you want your tool to be transparent. A browser may listen to OS input events (Windows messages telling it which keys were pressed or where the mouse was clicked), games may use DirectInput and yet other apps may subscribe to low-level system events or hooks.

For example browser automation:

- Using plugins/extensions gives you a JavaScript API that allows you to inspect pages, forms on those pages, modify browser behavior and whatnot.
- Browsers can also have their own external API. This can be done by linking to their DLLs, or passing command line arguments, or passing messages in other ways. For Firefox, this API is named ["Marionette"](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/marionette/Intro.html).
- Then there's Selenium, that provides a common API for various browsers. It controls them using "drivers".

Selenium "knows" how to drive a browser, as it's coded against the browser's APIs. Spy++ "knows" that it's inspecting a Win32 window and looks for known controls, their classes and their names so you could write another program to send specific messages to those specific controls of those specific applications.

As for "log in to Facebook", no, you cannot do that in a reasonable amount of time for the currently popular browsers if you want to code it from the ground on up.

You'll have to, in one way or the other, interface with the browser and ask for a handle to the username/password textboxes, enter data into them and then submit the form. Then you'll practically be rebuilding Selenium, so why not use that tool in the first place?

Or you'll have to scrape the pixels on the screen, recognize those textboxes, click the mouse there and send some keys. And then Facebook redesigns their login form and you'll have to start over.

**tl;dr**: use the right tool for the job. If you want to automate a site's UI, then use Selenium.

Comment: thank you so much, i was thinking there is another way to control mozilla out of selenium cause of different purposes. So there is not another kind of subject which provides universal automation besides does spy++ allows me to control win32 windows? I think you explained like that. I have tried to reach it's documantation but i guess it's not popular enough to have good information or i couldn't reach it.
It's not problem for me is it invisible or not, i am just trying to do things for myself.

Comment: Spy++ is only for inspecting processes, threads, windows and messages. It allows you to debug your Windows application, or look at how other applications are built.

Comment: Thank you, for web side i got all but for softwares and games side how does it works? for example like CSGO hack or LOL cheats how do they do that and how do they pull informations/control from like these apps or any another kind of app/game?

Comment: They read and manipulate the game's memory and/or network traffic.